# Call mvc controller with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to mvc and jQuery... and to web development in general really. I recently took over control of a site designed by a developer that we had to let go and the treeview control he had used needed to be changed for reasons that I won't get into here. But basically I need to be able to have resources be download on the click event of a node in the treeview. I know how to handle the event but I can't figure out how to make the call to my mvc controller through jquery. The path to the controller function I need to call to download the resource is /Resources/DownloadResource. Here's the code for it:

```
        public ActionResult DownloadResource(string id)
        {
            var resource =
                _resourceService.GetResourceQuery(new Specification<Resource>(r => r.ResourceId == new Guid(id))).FirstOrDefault();

        return new BinaryResult
        {
            FileName = resource.FileName,
            ContentType = string.Format("application/{0}", Path.GetExtension(resource.FileName)).Replace(".", ""),
            IsAttachment = true,
            Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(resource.FilePath)
        };
    }
```

I have tried something like `$.post("/Resources/DownloadResourceLink", { id: value });` and when I step through, everything is getting the correct values, but no download. Any help would definitely be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger the download from the browser, you need to use a synchronous way not ajax.

Look at this question: [Downloading a file onto client in ASP.NET MVC application using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028112/downloading-a-file-onto-client-in-asp-net-mvc-application-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).keypress(function (e) 
    {
        if (e.which == 13) 
        {
             location.href = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controllername")';
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [This](http://iridescence.no/post/Invoking-ASPNET-MVC-Actions-from-JavaScript-using-jQuery.aspx)
Basically you are just calling the MVC action address as the url property of your ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be how you are passing in the id.  In my experience, I have to append the data into the url *(/action/controller/id route)*

```
$.post("/Resources/DownloadResourceLink/" + value);
```

If that doesn't work, I'd make sure the [content type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) the call is expecting is correct for the download type.

If that still doesn't do it, then the issue may be the post.

I recommend you take a look at [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  The default is a get, which you may need for a download.  I don't know what the content type needs to be (you should be able to infer that from the action method), but your call would look something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Resources/DownloadResourceLink',
    params: { id }
});
```